# Модуль GPRS Shield Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino

Весной собрал девайс с этим модулем, всё работало до середины сентября, сейчас из 10 сеансов до сервера доходит 1-2. Монитор порта показал что в ответах модуля присутствуют лишние символы, например на команду    AT+SAPBR=3,1, "CONTYPE", "GPRS"    модуль отвечает   yyyyyyyyAT+SAPBR=3,1, "CONTYPE", "GPRS"
OK а при выполнении команды  AT+SAPBR=1,1> (включение передатчика) в большинстве случаев вообще перезагружается, и даже если команда пройдёт нормально то во время передачи информации точно перезагрузится. Впечатление, что не хватает питания, пробовал с 35 амперным БП - тоже самое.